# How to override the ActiveModel::SecurePassword.authenticate method?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I'm trying to override the `authenticate` method in this file: https://github.com/rails/rails/blob/f33d52c95217212cbacc8d5e44b5a8e3cdc6f5b3/activemodel/lib/active_model/secure_password.rb#L61

I have to make sure that if a user without `password_digest` tries to authenticate, the method returns false instead of raising `BCrypt::Errors::InvalidHash`

I have to do this because, in the past, we had another authentication system, and many users have a null password_digest. the authenticate method is used in different places and we cannot put an empty `password_digest` to the users without a password_digest.

I tried this:

```
# config/initializers/secure_password.rb

module ActiveModel
  module SecurePassword
    class InstanceMethodsOnActivation
      def authenticate(unencrypted_password)
        begin
          BCrypt::Password.new(password_digest).is_password?(unencrypted_password) && self
        rescue BCrypt::Errors::InvalidHash => e
          false
        end
      end
    end
  end
end
```

This is my test:

```
it 'should authenticate with false response if no digest (legacy password system)' do
  user.activate!
  user.update(password_digest: nil)
  expect(user.authenticate('test')).to be false
end
```

And the error message:

```
BCrypt::Errors::InvalidHash: invalid hash

  0) User should authenticate with false response if no digest (legacy password system)
     Failure/Error: expect(user.authenticate('test')).to be false

     BCrypt::Errors::InvalidHash:
       invalid hash
```

I update our app to Rails 6 and SecurePassword has been rewritten, I can't change the method again. I think the problem is that the authenticate method is now defined within the InstanceMethodsOnActivation's initialize method. I find it strange... And I don't know how to modify it.

Please anyone could help me?

Comment: What error are you getting, or otherwise why is it no longer working?

Comment: Hi @TamerShlash, I don't have an error, it just doesn't work (raise BCyrpt::Errors::InvalidHash instead of false). I'm going to update my question with my test. It no longer works because SecurePassword has been refactored between rails 5.2 and rails 6.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you don't need to monkey-patch the gem implementation, because I think the super-trick would already be sufficient enough in your case:

```
class User < ApplicationRecord
  def authenticate(*args)
    if password_digest.nil? # or `.blank?` (if you have '' as default instead of nil)
      false
    else
      # else, proceed normally
      super(*args)
      # `super` alone also works, as it automatically pass in all arguments
    end
  end
end
```

#### Sample Usage:

```
user = User.new
user.password_digest = nil

puts user.authenticate('somepassword')
# => false
```

### Regarding Your "concerns" problem:

- It should look like the following:

```
# app/models/concerns/your_own_named_concern.rb

module YourOwnNamedConcern
  extend ActiveSupport::Concern

  included do
    def authenticate(*args)
      if password_digest.nil?
        false
      else
        super(*args)
      end
    end
  end
end

# app/models/user.rb
class User < ApplicationRecord
  include YourOwnNamedConcern

  has_secure_password
end

# app/models/admin.rb
class Admin < ApplicationRecord
  include YourOwnNamedConcern
end
```

#### Sample Usage:

```
user = User.new
user.password_digest = nil

puts user.authenticate('somepassword')
# => false

admin = Admin.new
admin.password_digest = nil

puts admin.authenticate('somepassword')
# => false
```

Comment: Thank you Jay-Ar, it works (: Just one last question: I have the User and Admin models, so I tried to use this code in a concern, but it doesn't work (there's no error, it acts as if the code is not included). Do you know why?

Comment: How did you write your concerns? It should be something like above (I'll update my answer)

Comment: @escanxr It's possible that the concern may not work depending if Rails does some metaprogramming, and the `ancestors` chain gets shuffled unexpectedly. If this happened, let me know, I'll update my answer above.

Comment: @escanxr I've just tested this out on a fresh Rails 6 project using `bcrypt`, and I tested that the concern works. So above should also work for you :)

Comment: Thank you very much! I forgot the `included` block... It works perfectly now (: